# We graduated to Public Beta!

Tags: discussion

Congrats fellas!  We have graduated to Public Beta. So, we should be having a greater influx of users. And from now onwards, we will be tracked and our stats would be very important.

[image]

So, yaay!  Time to celebrate!

Comment: @LiveForever Yeah, makes sense.  But, as a member of several beta sites, I can vouch for the fact that the qns per day stat is very important.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great to have had any kind of announcement prior the publication.

Around one hour before it happened, our landing page still said "it will be private for at least 8 more days". I was planning a major clean up of tags and questions with all of you guys 2-3 days before the launch.

Now it happened and all the privileges are gone and there is a lot of work to do. Well, grind more rep then, I guess :)

Comment: The users(people who have comitted to) generally receive an email when the site is going into public beta.

Comment: Yes, when it happenes, but not _before_ :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  It helps us get ready for the big _Public Beta_ event!  Anyways, let's contribute more and propel it to graduation! :)