# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation, 7-questions

As we [graduate to public beta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/98/87) it is time to nominate some [pro tem moderators](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) to look after the Ethereum Stack Exchange community.

We are looking for some people with…

- reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

*... bonus points for*:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

#### How to nominate

- One nomination per answer.
- You can nominate yourself or any other member. Self-nominations are even encouraged.
- **If you are nominated,** please edit the post to accept (or decline) the nomination. You can even add a paragraph to tell us a little bit about yourself and your involvement with this site.
- Link the name to the user's profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

And please **vote, vote, vote** for the folks you would like to see represent this site!

Who will be our first human exception handler?

Comment: Bonus points for experience in moderating other stackexchange sites?

Comment: @paulmorriss No, not at all. While we allow folks to moderator multiple sites, we prefer moderators to **focus on a specific community.**

Comment: @RobertCartaino I was thinking of someone who had done it, but isn't now. I think it's a small advantage, but there may be several other more important things.

Comment: @paulmorriss This site is a grass-roots effort of Etherium users, so we prefer not to reinforce the notion of an "expert" generation of SE moderators. Suggesting that experience in moderation is an advantage will only discourage folks who don't have it from participating otherwise. For a site where broad, crowd-sourced governance it absolutely *critical,* that would be very unfortunate.

Comment: hmm How to nominate in the format everyone is doing?  The flairs are added automatically after "I would like to nominate ..." ?

Comment: i added the flairs manually. can help with that. or just copy and paste and change the user ids in the links.

Comment: @5chdn Thanks, I just figured out we paste the link itself, instead of trying to edit the "code" which all looks the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: profile for Hudson Jameson at Ethereum Stack Exchange, Q&A for users of Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network]


[image: profile for Hudson Jameson at Ethereum Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for users of Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network]


[profile for Hudson Jameson on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7191282.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/7191282)

Well, since self-nomination is "encouraged", I'll nominate myself :P

I am a DApp developer, Ethereum enthusiast, and volunteer much of my time coordinating Ethereum volunteer activities and helping others learn about blockchains.

Experience:

- [Ethereum Subreddit Mod](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/)
- [Scrum Master of the Ethereum Homestead Milestone Documentation
  effort](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/42vuik/homestead_documentation_initiative/)
- [Speaker at DEVCon1 Ethereum Conference in London Nov. 2015. Talk was
  over the community and getting involved (including a shout-out to the
  Ethereum Stack Exchange initiative) (Click for YouTube of Talk)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh8g5BrqFxY)
- Guest speaker at the first Ethereum Tampa Meetup
- Participated in the [Ether.Camp hackathon](http://hack.ether.camp/) to create the [Motivate DApp](https://github.com/Souptacular/motivate-dapp).
- [One of 7 members of the first Ethereum decentralized autonomous organization that holds over $10,000 in funds for the Dogethereum bridge bounty.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/41ohhr/the_doge_connection_bounty_dao_is_live_and_working/)

Profiles:

[Ethereum Reddit [Mod]](https://www.reddit.com/user/Souptacular/)

[Stack Exchange Parent Profile](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/299/hudson-jameson)

[Stack Exchange Meta Profile](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/users/299/hudson-jameson)

[Personal Website](http://www.hudsonjameson.com)

### Relevant Moderation Badges (10):

Commentator, Scholar, Motarboard, Informed, Critic, Autobiographer, Custodian x2, Editor, Teacher

I would love the oppurtunity to mod for the Ethereum community on our StackExchange :)

Comment: Hudson has demonstrated exceptional leadership in the community, taking on the Homestead documentation initiative and Mod responsibilities for the subreddit. He is also a very knowledgeable developer and excellent communicator.

Comment: very cool! let's try to graduate the site before devcon2 :)

Comment: @5chdn Oh we will :)

Comment: Scholar, Mortarboard, Informed, Autobiographer and Teacher don't seem relevant to moderation. I would expect users to list only badges from the section "Moderation Badges" under that headline, although I can see why Commentator might get mentioned as well.

Comment: Be aware that moderating reddit and moderating Stack Exchange are very different. You'll need to get used to that, and make sure that the two styles don't contaminate one another.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: Thanks for the advice. I am doing my best to get used to moderating StackExchange. So far I have found that the biggest difference is that on Reddit you primarily moderate opinions and on StackExchange you moderate whether a post is well made, accurate, and conducive to the StackExchange Q&A format.

Comment: @HudsonJameson That's about right. And certainly when I moderated reddit, there's not so much of a stigma attached to vote fraud, whereas on SE vote fraud is a *very* serious incident.

Answer (score 18):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1313419.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1313419)

I would like to nominate **5chdn**. They have been very helpful in making sure every question gets answered and is edited to be as clear as possible and has helped organize the tags.

---

**Relevant moderation badges** (12): Civic Duty, Tag Editor, Vox Populi, Citizen Patrol, Suffrage, Commentator, Organizer, Quorum, Beta, Critic, Editor, Custodian

---

Edit by **5chdn**: *challenge accepted*. :)

Comment: I see that @5chdn also have experience participating in a beta site (SustainableLiving), which would be a very helpful experience to have, as moderating this site through it's beta stages would be very similar to how other beta sites operate!

Answer (score 13):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2739006.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2739006/)

I would like to nominate **Tjaden Hess**. He is a DApp developer and Ethereum enthusiast, shows decent activity and with the site-wide highest answer rate everyone can still learn from him.

---

**Relevant moderation badges** (10): Enlightened, Vox Populi, Citizen Patrol, Suffrage, Commentator, Quorum, Beta, Critic, Editor, Custodian

---

Edit by **Tjaden Hess**: *Thank you, and I accept.*

Some links:

- [Reddit](http://reddit.com/user/tjade273)
- ether.camp Hackathon [Motivate](https://github.com/Souptacular/motivate-dapp) Team
- [Github](https://github.com/tjade273)

Comment: Tjaden is highly knowledgeable and has proven himself as a talented developer, teacher, and community member.

Answer (score 10):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7676417.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/7676417)

I would like to nominate **eth** who has the highest reputation gained in our community and helped with the most edits a single users ever did to ensure quality standards throughout our site.

---

**Relevant moderation badges** (9): Tag Editor, Citizen Patrol, Commentator, Organizer, Quorum, Beta, Critic, Editor, Custodian

---

Edit by **eth**:  *Thank you and I accept*

Comment: eth has asked many pertinent questions and been a very active contributor.

Answer (score 10):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/388756.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/388756)

I would like to nominate **Jeff Coleman**.  He's a full time blockchain consultant active in the space since 2010, and an eager follower of Ethereum for the last two years.

Edit by **Jeff Coleman**: *I very much appreciate the nomination, but unfortunately don't have the time available required to be an effective moderator. I must regretfully decline.*

Answer (score 5):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/88081.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/88081)

I would like to nominate **mids** who is the most active voter in our community and has the best collection in relevant moderation badges which shows his dedication for this stackexchange site.

---

**Relevant moderation badges** (10): Civic Duty, Vox Populi, Suffrage, Commentator, Organizer, Quorum, Beta, Critic, Editor, Custodian

Comment: I accept my nomination as moderator

Answer (score 4):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/35254.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/35254)

I would like to nominate **nessence** (Alex Leverington). I'm an Ethereum core contributor and dapp developer. I started contributing to the c++ client in Feb of '14 and was one of the first ethdevs hired in Berlin. I would like to help people learn more about Ethereum.

- ethereum contributor (c++ client, p2p protocol)
- Understand the Yellow Paper ;)
- Organizer and speaker at DEVCON1 (@hudson was an awesome volunteer!)

I don't have a high score here or at the meta site however I voted for the exchange on area 51 and have extensive experience with ethereum.

Answer (score 3):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/438934.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/438934/nikhil-m?tab=accounts)

I would like to be a moderator on this community because i am very much interested in Ethereum.

I am familiar with Stackexchange for almost 4 years. Here are some of my profiles on other SE-sites:

1. [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/438934/nikhil-m?tab=accounts)
2. [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4471/nikhil-m)
3. [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/259/nikhil-m)

[image]

Other Activities.

1. Will start Ethereum Meetup in Trivandrum India.
2. [Drupal Top Users in SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1031/4471)

PS: I know its a serious crowd that i am participating in and I respect each one of you.

---

**Relevant moderation badges** (8): Tag Editor, Commentator, Organizer, Quorum, Beta, Critic, Editor, Custodian

Answer (score 1):

[image: ethereum main site flair]
[image: ethereum meta site flair]
[network profile flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/902272.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/902272)

I would like to nominate **ThePiachu**.  Although he just joined yesterday, he started [asking questions about Ethereum over 6 months ago](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum?sort=newest&pagesize=50).

If he is interested in our community, I think we would benefit from his community-building, experience, and participation in other related communities such as Bitcoin, Cryptography, Mathematics.

Comment: Thank you for the nomination, but I must decline. While I used to moderate Bitcoin.SE, I currently don't have enough time to devote to the site to be an effective moderator (hence why I'm no longer a Bitcoin.SE mod). Best of luck to you regardless.